# How do I search GitHub issues "created in the last seven days"?

Tags: github

We'd like to list all GitHub issues created in the last seven (or, *n*) days. This is a relative time window.

We don't want to use a specific date, because we'd like to create a link that is always correct (so we can link to the report of recent issues).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-based-on-when-an-issue-or-pull-request-was-created-or-last-updated

`created:2016-12-01..2016-12-08`

Will output issue created during these 7 days.

Comment: Thanks. But, unfortunately, that's still using real dates. I'm looking for a solution that does not use exact dates. Instead, I'd like to use a relative date (e.g. "7 days ago").

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [bookmarklet](https://gist.github.com/caseywatts/c0cec1f89ccdb8b469b1), like I have, to for example, show your merged PRs last 7 days within a repo. Here's my bookmarklet:

```
data:text/html,<script>document.location.href%3D%60https://github.com/calcom/cal.com/pulls%3Fq%3Dis%253Apr%2Bauthor%253Aleog%2Bis%253Aclosed%2Bmerged%253A%253E%24%7Bnew Date((new Date).setDate((new Date).getDate()-7)).toISOString().split("T")%5B0%5D%7D%60%3B</script>
```

Comment: Note that if you want this to work from the New Tab page in Chrome, you'll need to construct it slightly differently: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56793918/388951

Comment: Thanks @danvk, works great on new tab now too, updated the snippet 

Answer (score 0):

This bookmarklet will show you open issues that were created in the last 7 days, by calculating the appropriate date when the bookmarklet is clicked:

```js
data:text/html,<script>document.location.href='https://github.com/my-org/my-repo/issues?q=is:issue+is:open+created:>' + new Date((new Date).setDate((new Date).getDate()-7)).toISOString().split("T")[0];</script>
```

Make sure you update the repo URL to whichever repo you'd like to check. You can also change `7` in the above snippet to however many days back you'd like to look.