# can you run javascript commands whilst going onto a web page?

Tags: javascript, url

I want to be able to go onto e.g stackoverflow.com whilst doing `alert("hi);`

is there a way to do it in the link(e.g. `stackoverflow.com&alert("hi");`)?

unfortunately that doesnt work.

when I do that it doesnt even think that it is a valid url,

please try find a way.

also, I am on a chromebook, and cannot use dev tools as my administrator blocked them.

Comment: Open your browser's development tools, navigate to the console, and execute whatever code you like right there.

Comment: Just imagine the security nightmare if you could attach executable commands directly into URLs!

Comment: the problem is though, that I'm trying to run bookmarklets on "chrome://" links, but they have blocked bookmarklets on their websites. so instead I tried to do this.

Comment: You can install a userscript extension like [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/) that can executes scripts on a particular domain pattern.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? What do you intend to use it for?

Comment: @ArielBlau: If Chrome dev tools are administratively disabled then you *probably* won't be able to add custom extensions or install custom software either.  But that's exactly what you'd need.  Either the built-in development tools or a custom browser extension.  Simply *adding something to the URL* won't do anything unless the target site writes code to read from the URL and execute whatever it finds, which is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

"whilst going onto a web page" is the problem here. You can manually open developer tools with the `F12` hotkey (or `CTRL+SHIFT+i`) and paste your code there, but you can't execute JavaScript the moment that someone clicks a link and a website is open because that would be a really big security hole. Running your own JavaScript whitin a website context could lead to session stealing or user impersonation if your JavaScript is malicious, so making a user click a link and running your own javaScript code included in the link could lead to potential attacks that you want to avoid as an Internet user.

That's why web developers should take care of [Cross-site scripting attacks (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) when developing websites, although nowadays almost all UI frameworks/libraries take care of them. Back in the days it was easier to have these kind of problems. For example [MySpace had this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_(computer_worm)).

EDIT:
The are some options:

- You can install an extension like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and create your own userscript or
- There's a usually forgotten way to run your own JavaScript code: You can first enter the website, and after that write in the URL: `javascript:alert("asd")`. It will run the code like running it in the developer console. You can also bookmark the JavaScript code. It leads to 2 actions: first open the link, second click the bookmarked JavaScript, but at least you can run your own code. This is the old-school way of having userscripts.
  [image]

Comment: sorry forgot to add I'm on a chromebook + administrator blocked dev tools, also I dont think you can do that on "chrome://" links. (I edited my question to add this)

Comment: so why dont bookmarklets run on "chrome://" links?

Comment: I'm not sure about bookmarklets and `chrome://` links. Which `chrome://` link are you trying to access?

Comment: @ArielBlau if you open an empty tab, or navigate to an internal chrome settings page like `chrome://about`, you cannot execute JavaScript bookmarklets. I have one called "Last Updated" with the value of `javascript:alert(document.lastModified)` and it never worked on any of those pages. See: [javascript bookmarklet does not work in new tab in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794455/1762224). JavaScript is disabled from running on those pages.

Comment: any e.g: "chrome://chrome-urls" - a simple html site - doesnt run bookmarklets.

Comment: would it be possible to use "x = window.open('chrome://e.g');" and then x.write("<script>alert('hi')</script>")?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl oh what a pity. Nice info. Thank you for the details.

Comment: @ArielBlau is not supported. If you do so, Chrome returns an error: "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://chrome-urls/". I guess is impossible to run custom JavaScript in `chrome://` urls, I guess because of security reasons. There is the entire Chrome privacy, passwords, certificates and whatever configurations.

Comment: instead, could I find the src of chrome://chrome-urls using javascript, then run it, but adding my extra code? or will it not be able to find the source?

Comment: @ArielBlau If you mean to find where this file is located so you can modify it, that is not possible as the `chrome://` websites are not HTML and JavaScript code per se, but they are rendered internally. You need to download the entire chromium source code, modify it (is not JavaScript, is C) and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a userscript extension like [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/) that can executes scripts on a particular domain pattern.

Just create a userscript that alerts the user when they visit a domain that matches the `@match` config.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Stack Overflow Greeter
// @namespace     Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match         https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant         none
// @version       1.0.0
// @author        Mr. Polywhirl
// @description   Alert "Hi!" on Stack Overflow
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
  alert('Hi!');
})();
```