# Trying to make a javascript bookmark to add date of last sunday and date of next saturday

Tags: javascript, firefox

Im trying to make a javascript booklet and the web address stays mostly constant, just the date changes

I HAVE THIS by adapting an old bookmark to work for this:

```
javascript:function url(){          
var date = new Date();                
var m = date.getMonth()+1;         
var d = date.getDate();     
var y = date.getYear();   
var h = date.getHours();   
var hs = date.getHours()-1;      
if(m < 10){m = '0' + m;}         
if(d < 10){d = '0' + d;}          
return 'XXXXXX'+ y +'-' + m + '-' + d + 'XXXXX' + y + '-' + m + '-' d + 'xxxxxx';  } window.open(url(),"_parent");
```

I need the output to be EXAMPLE: website.com/2024-02-04/info/2024-02-10/stuff
where the only things that need to be updated are the dates and if they can auto load this weeks first day of the week (sunday) and this weeks last day of the week (saturday)

javascipt and booklets are new to me so please forgive my knowledge gaps

Comment: `... + '-' d + ...` - you're missing a `+` between `'-'` and `d` in your function's `return`.

Comment: Also, using `date.getYear()` will give you `124`, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98124/). Perhaps it would be better if you were to use `date.getFullYear()`, since that's in accord with what you're trying to get, i.e. website.com/2024-02-04/....

Comment: so like this?
`javascript:function url(){
var date = new Date();
var m = date.getMonth()+1;
var d = date.getDate();
var y = date.getFullYear();
if(m < 10){m = '0' + m;}
if(d < 10){d = '0' + d;}
return 'XXXXXX'+ y +'-' + m + '-' + d + 'XXXXX' + y + '-' + m + '-' + d + 'xxxxxx';  } window.open(url(),"_parent");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is presented in its unminified version. In order to be able to use it in a bookmarklet, you would have to minify it.

```js
function getNewDate(dayName) {
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();

    // case for when we want Sunday
    if(dayName.toLowerCase() === 'sunday') {
        // reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay
        // day === 0 means it's Sunday
        var diff = date.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -7 : 0);
    // case when it's not Sunday. We're assuming it's always Saturday, otherwise. Not good, generally, but alright in this case
    } else {
        var diff = date.getDate() + (6 - day) + (day >= 6 ? 7 : 0);
    }
    var newDate= new Date(date.setDate(diff));

    var m = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = newDate.getDate();
    var y = newDate.getFullYear();

    if(m < 10) {
        m = '0' + m;
    }
    
    if(d < 10) {
        d = '0' + d;
    }
    
    return y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
}

function url() {
    var date_1 = getNewDate('sunday');
    var date_2 = getNewDate('saturday');

    return 'website.com/' + date_1 + '/info/' + date_2 + '/stuff';
}

// When using it as a bookmarklet, comment out the line below...
alert(url());
// ... and remove the comment from the one below
// window.open(url(),"_parent");
```

When minified (and with `window.open` instead of `alert`):

```js
function getNewDate(e){var t=new Date,a=t.getDay();if("sunday"===e.toLowerCase())var r=t.getDate()-a+(0===a?-7:0);else var r=t.getDate()+(6-a)+(a>=6?7:0);var n,u=new Date(t.setDate(r)),g=u.getMonth()+1,s=u.getDate();return g<10&&(g="0"+g),s<10&&(s="0"+s),u.getFullYear()+"-"+g+"-"+s}function url(){var e=getNewDate("sunday"),t=getNewDate("saturday");return"website.com/"+e+"/info/"+t+"/stuff"} window.open(url(),"_parent");
```

---

Now, in order to be able to use this as a bookmarklet, you would have to do a couple of things.

1. You *might* have to use `encodeURI` on your minified JS, to make runnable in some browsers. Chrome and Firefox work fine with the minified bookmarklet as it is.
2. Trying to use the bookmarklet in a new tab in Chrome will not work (in Firefox it does work). I haven't been able to find the exact reason for this - there is a SO comment (by blackcatweb) in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794455/6133426), which mentions that the Javascript engine is not available in a new tab.
3. You would need to prefix your URL with the correct protocol - `http`, or `https`.
4. The code would also need to be prefaced with `javascript:`, if it's to be used as a bookmarklet

Comment: excellent that worked thank you! I did have to add "javascript:function getNewDate(e)..." the javascript: and it worked as is

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added the fourth thing to consider, since it was omitted - the `javascript:` as a prefix, in order for the code to be usable (I wouldn't have noticed it, if you hadn't mentioned it).