# How would I search Github issues created in the last x days?

Tags: github, github-search

> Also [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729663/how-do-i-search-github-issues-created-in-the-last-seven-days) but in 2016 and with no working answer.

I'd like to search for issues created x number of days ago, but can only find how to search using actual (hardcoded, if you will) dates. For example, I want to search for issues created less than 7 days ago.

I've read through their [search syntax documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax) and cannot figure out a way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, as mentioned in their [Search Syntax docs](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-dates):

> You can search for dates that are earlier or later than another date,
> or that fall within a range of dates, by using >, >=, <, <=, and range
> queries. Date formatting must follow the ISO8601 standard, which is
> YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day).

Meaning, unfortunately, they do not provide an out-of-the-box approach for you to do this relative searching.

If you're using the UI search, you can use the sort to be by `Newest`, while if you're using the API/GraphQL, you will need to write a function to take in the `x` number of days, generate a compliant `ISO8601` date and pass to your request.

Not the answer you were hoping for, but I hope this helps clarify it.