# How can I get all issues which were created today?

Tags: github

I can use `is:issue created:2023-03-06` to get all issues which were created on that date. However, I would like to make this dynamic: Instead of entering a concrete date, I would like to do

`is:issue created:today`

Is there a search term like that?

Resources:

- [GitHub Docs - Search by](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-when-an-issue-or-pull-request-was-created-or-last-updated)
- [Similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026709/how-would-i-search-github-issues-created-in-the-last-x-days)